# str.extract overwriting the entire dataframe column in Python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, dataframe

I'm at Jupyter Notebook working with Python.

I'm having trouble using `Series.str.extract`.
Extracting text for a given column when it occurs in another column works smoothly.
In the second extraction for which there was no occurrence (match) previously, the script saves the new match but deletes the previous ones, I need both occurrences to be saved, how to solve it?

Below script and example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

dicionario = {'nome_adm': ['CC Brasil', 
                   'ABC Futuro',
                   'Tabuao'], 
              
              'nome': ['brasil fundo de investimento em cotas ', 
                   'previ futuro multimercado',
                   'brasil handmade ii multimercado credito privado'], 
                   
          'publico': [' publico em geral ', 
                   'investidores profissionais',
                   'previdenciario'], 
                  
          'texto': ['qual o seu publico alvo. o fundo recebera recursos de investidores qualificados que 777', 
                    'publico alvo o fundo recebera recursos de publico alvo capitulo i profissionais que o capitulo i',
                   'publico que tem VGBL e previdencia']}


data = pd.DataFrame(dicionario)

data['texto_curto'] = None
data

# = OK
data['texto_curto'] = data['texto'].str.extract(r'(publico alvo.{0,5})',flags=re.IGNORECASE)
data

# = NOK - overwriting
data['texto_curto'] = data.loc[data['nome_adm'] == 'Tabuao']['texto'].str.extract(r'(vgbl.*)',flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.M)
data
```

What is desired is that information is always added to the "short text" column and that it is not deleted. In this case, the entire "texto curto" column should be filled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use a **mask** and `loc[]` to update only rows that you want to update
- additionally use `expand=False` parameter so `expand()` returns a series not a data frame

```
mask = data['nome_adm'] == 'Tabuao'
data.loc[mask, 'texto_curto'] = data.loc[mask]['texto'].str.extract(r'(vgbl.*)',flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.M, expand=False)
data
```

#### output

|  | nome_adm | nome | publico | texto | texto_curto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | CC Brasil | brasil fundo de investimento em cotas | publico em geral | qual o seu publico alvo. o fundo recebera recursos de investidores qualificados que 777 | publico alvo. o f |
| 1 | ABC Futuro | previ futuro multimercado | investidores profissionais | publico alvo o fundo recebera recursos de publico alvo capitulo i profissionais que o capitulo i | publico alvo o fu |
| 2 | Tabuao | brasil handmade ii multimercado credito privado | previdenciario | publico que tem VGBL e previdencia | VGBL e previdencia |